# how to get table td value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I tried to use JQuery to get the td value from the html code below. Followed some suggestions in the forum but doesn't work

code at: [/http://jsfiddle.net/zqv05ab8/][1]

```
<tr>
  <td>   <input id="go" type="button" value="Go" /></td>
  <td>Test 1</td>
  <td><span>
       <table id="table1" >
          <tr>
            <th >Column A</th>
            <th >Column B</th>
            <th >Column C</th>
            <th>Column D</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td >AAA</td>
            <td >BBB</td>
            <td >CCC</td>
            <td> DDD</td>
          </tr>     </table>
     
    </span></td>
    <td><span>09/23/2020</span></td></tr>
 
jquery code is:

$('#go').click( function() {
     
   var trs=$('#table1').children().find('tr').length;   
     alert(trs);     
       
  var  tmp1=$(this).closest('#table1').find('tr:first td:first').html();
  alert('tmp1: '+ tmp1);
  
  var firstTdFirstRow = $(this).closest('tr').find('#table1 tr:first td:first').html();  
  alert('firstTdFirstRow: ' + firstTdFirstRow);
   
   var trstr=$('#table1').children().find('tr:first td:first').html();
   aler('trstr: '+ trstr);
    
    });


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/zqv05ab8/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.closest('tr')` then use `.find()` to find table inside `tr` where button is clicked then using this get all `th` and `td` values.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#go').click(function() {

  var trs = $('#table1').children().find('tr').length;
  //getclosest tr -> thn find table inside that where eq(0) refer first td do same for all
  var tmp1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('#table1 tr:eq(0) th:eq(0)').html();
  alert('tmp1: ' + tmp1);
  var firstTdFirstRow = $(this).closest('tr').find('#table1 tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)').html();
  alert('firstTdFirstRow: ' + firstTdFirstRow);
  //get all datas using each loop
  $(this).closest('tr').find('#table1 tr').children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text().trim())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input id="go" type="button" value="Go" /></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td><span>
       <table id="table1">
          <tr>
            <th >Column A</th>
            <th >Column B</th>
            <th >Column C</th>
            <th>Column D</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td >AAA</td>
            <td >BBB</td>
            <td >CCC</td>
            <td> DDD</td>
          </tr>     </table>
     
    </span></td>
    <td><span>09/23/2020</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use eq works!

var tmp1 = $('#table1').find('tr:eq(1)').find('td:eq(2)').html();

for variable, use colindex to get the row, then td cell value

var tmp2=$(this).closest('tr').find('#table1').find('tr:eq('+ colindex+ ')').find('td:eq(0)').html();